# Table format is not proper

Tags: tables

I have a weird problem. My table is not formatted properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Dataset Description}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l l c c c|}
\hline \\
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \\
\hline \\
Adult  & Binary & 32561 & 16281 & 123\\[0.05cm]
Galaxy & 90.44 & 90.12 & 87.94 & 86.47 \\[0.05cm]
Mediamill & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\[0.05cm]
Rcv & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\[0.05cm]
Siam &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
Scene &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
Yeast &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:data_desc}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You don't need (and shouldn't have) `\\ ` after the `\hline` commands.

Comment: @PaulGessler, Thanks.  I thought that \\ simply starts a new row.  In that case, if I want to add some space above and below \hline, what should I do ?

Comment: @Sham: Please consider dropping the vertical lines in that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some methods to achieve larger vertical spacings

The second table below contains `\multirow`, empty extra rows, empty extra rows with reduced line skip and a `bigstrut` approach

- There might be some other ways...
- The provided lengths are a choice of my own and can be changed of course

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newlength{\myextraspace}
\setlength{\myextraspace}{0.05cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Dataset Description}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}


\begin{tabular}{|*{2}l*{3}c|}
\hline 
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \\
\hline 
Adult  & Binary & 32561 & 16281 & 123\\[0.05cm]
Galaxy & 90.44 & 90.12 & 87.94 & 86.47 \\[0.05cm]
Mediamill & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\[0.05cm]
Rcv & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\[0.05cm]
Siam &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
Scene &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
Yeast &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\[0.05cm]
\hline 
\end{tabular}

Now the changed table




\begin{tabular}{|*{2}l*{3}c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Name} & \multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Train Size} & \multirow{2}{*}{Test Size} & \multirow{2}{*}{Feature Size} \tabularnewline
& & & & \tabularnewline
\hline 

& & & & \tabularnewline
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \tabularnewline
& & & & \tabularnewline
\hline 

& & & & \tabularnewline[-1ex]
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \tabularnewline
& & & & \tabularnewline[-1ex]
\hline 
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \bigstrut\tabularnewline
\hline 

Adult  & Binary & 32561 & 16281 & 123.00\tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Galaxy & 90.44 & 90.12 & 87.94 & 86.47 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Mediamill & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Rcv & 97.86 & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Siam &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Scene &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
Yeast &  80.37 & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \tabularnewline[\myextraspace]
\hline 
\end{tabular}


\label{tab:data_desc}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{spacing}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = spacing,
  tableposition = top,
  font = small,
  labelfont = sc
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{Dataset Description.}
 \label{tab:data_desc}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S[table-format = 2.2]} S[table-format = 3.2]}
   \toprule
    Name      & {Type}   & {Train Size} & {Test Size} & {Feature Size} \\
   \midrule
    Adult     & {Binary} & {32561}      & {16281}     & 123.00         \\
    Galaxy    & 90.44    & 90.12        & 87.94       &  86.47         \\
    Mediamill & 97.86    & 97.89        & 97.86       &  97.76         \\
    Rcv       & 97.86    & 97.89        & 97.86       &  97.76         \\
    Siam      & 80.37    & 80.62        & 80.20       &  79.19         \\
    Scene     & 80.37    & 80.62        & 80.20       &  79.19         \\
    Yeast     & 80.37    & 80.62        & 80.20       &  79.19         \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Simple method to achieve beautiful table is use of `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Dataset Description}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%1.2
\begin{tabular}{l l c c c}
    \toprule
Name & Type & Train Size & Test Size & Feature Size \\
    \midrule 
Adult       & Binary    & 32561 & 16281 & 123   \\
Galaxy      & 90.44     & 90.12 & 87.94 & 86.47 \\
Mediamill   & 97.86     & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\
Rcv         & 97.86     & 97.89 & 97.86 & 97.76 \\
Siam        &  80.37    & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\
Scene       &  80.37    & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\
Yeast       &  80.37    & 80.62 & 80.20 & 79.19 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:data_desc}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

I you like to have more spacing between row, then adjust factor in `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}` to desired value. Of course, this table intentionally  hasn't vertical lines.
[image]